# How to print the line breaks of a JSON attribute using Python?

Tags: python, json

I have the following situation:

- I have the following JSON file:

  ```
  {
     "name":"whatever",
     "lyric":"here comes the music
        another line
        whatever...
        bla bla bla
        final"
  }
  ```
- the next step would be loading the JSON file and change the attribute `"name"` to the `"songs real name"`.
- The final step would be writing the JSON to an output file, keeping the same input format (to make easier the JSON reading ), but it does print the lines break as escaped characters, like that:

  ```
   {
      "name":"songs real name",    "lyric":"here comes the music  \n
       another line \n
       whatever... \n
       bla bla bla \n
       final"
  }
  ```

Desired output:

```
{
   "name":"songs real name",
   "lyric":"here comes the music
      another line
      whatever...
      bla bla bla
      final"
}
```

That's the python code:

```
with open(file, "r") as data_file:    
    json_data=data_file.read()
data_file.close()
json_data["name"]="song's real name"

with open(outputfile)
    jsonFile.write(json.dumps(data,indent=4, sort_keys=True)
```

everything works fine, except that it is not printing the lines break.

Comment: What are the variables data and jsonFile?

Comment: What do you think? data is the data that I am working with, and jsonFile is the output file.

Comment: so should be like this: with open('output.txt', 'w') as jsonFile: jsonFile.write('Hi there!'). I guess you are opening the file two times. One in the part of code that we cannot see and another time when you do: with open(outputfile)

Comment: the problem was that it was writing into the file the lines break of a json attribute as a escaped character, therefore I had to replace the escaped characterd "\\n" by unescaped char: "\n", and that worked fine. So, in the output file I finally got the result I would like. See below.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the answer, basicaly what I did was a replace over a json.dumps:

```
with open(file, "r") as data_file:    
json_data=data_file.read()
data_file.close()
json_data["name"]="song's real name"

with open(outputfile)
    jsonFile.write(json.dumps(data,indent=4, sort_keys=True, separators=(',', ': ')).replace('\\n','\n'))
```

after that, I got the output file as I would like:

> { 
>     "name" : "songs real name", 
>     "lyric" : "here comes the music 
>        another line 
>        whatever... 
>        bla bla bla 
>        final"
>   }

Thank you guys.