# How to get line breaks of a JSON attribute using Python?

Tags: python, json, newline, python-sphinx

JSON file :

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "item1": "/xyz"
        },
        {
            "item2": "/yzx"
        },
        {
            "item3": "/zxy"
        }
    ]
}
```

Python Code :

```
def funct(request):
    input = ''

    # Request body
    data = maybe_str(request.data())
    if data:
        if is_json(request.headers.get('Content-Type', '')):
            input = json.dumps(data, indent=2, sort_keys=True,
                           separators=(',', ': '))
        else:
            input = data

    return input
```

The python function returns a formatted string and then places it within Sphinx CodeBlock.

Output :

```
{ "items": [ { "item1": "/xyz", "item2": "/yzx", "item3": "/zxy" }, { "item1": "/xyz", "item2": "/yzx", "item3": "/zxy" } ] }
```

Desired Output:

```
{
"items": [
    {
      "item1": "/xyz",
      "item2": "/yzx",
      "item3": "/zxy"
    },
    {
      "item1": "/xyz",
      "item2": "/yzx",
      "item3": "/zxy"
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried using `.replace('\\n','\n')` from this [stackoverflow issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39414569/how-to-print-the-line-breaks-of-a-json-attribute-using-python) but still didnt work.

Edit: I have changed some variable names. I used "input" here just as an example

Comment: Please provide a [mre], for starters use a static JSON string, pass that along to `json.dumps` as you are currently doing and show your Sphinx code. If that is still reproducing your issue post it as a question. Otherwise keep adding more stuff related to your current code.

Answer (score 1):

```
def funct(request):
    input = ''

    # Request body
    data = maybe_str(request.data())
    if data:
        if is_json(request.headers.get('Content-Type', '')):
            input = json.dumps(data, indent=2, sort_keys=True,
                       separators=(',', ': '))
        else:
            input = data

    return json.dumps(input, indent=4) # returns prettified json str
```

This solution works for me in a python3 shell. In case this does not help, you can try using `simplejson`, `ujson`, or `json5`, which all are also able to format JSON.

And also, you should not use `input` as a variable name, because it's a reserved word — try using `json_input` instead.

Comment: `input` is not a reserved word, but a name of a built-in function. Thus it works fine as a local variable name. However, for easier readability, such names (e.g. `input`, `max`, `NameError`) should be avoided for local variables. There are >150 builtins and >35 keywords in Python.

Comment: Unfortunaetly it didn't work. I am getting output like this: `{\n \"items\": [\n {\n \"item1\": \"xyz\",\n \"item2\": \"/yzx\",\n \"item3\": \"/zxy\"\n }`