# Why am I not getting line breaks of a JSON attribute using python in Sphinxcontrib-httpexample?

Tags: python, json, newline, python-sphinx

I am trying to add a new tab in sphinxcontrib-httpexample like `curl`, `httpie`, `python-request`. I have made the required changes and everything is working apart from the output format.

JSON file :

```
POST /plone/front-page/@aliases HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46c2VjcmV0
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "items": [
        {
            "path": "/new-alias"
        },
        {
            "path": "/old-alias"
        },
        {
            "path": "/final-alias"
        }
    ]
}
```

Python Code (i will add it in [this file](https://github.com/collective/sphinxcontrib-httpexample/blob/master/src/sphinxcontrib/httpexample/builders.py)):

```
def build_plone_javascript_command(request):
    javascript_code = 'createAliasesMutation'
    redir_input2 = ''

    # Request body
    data = maybe_str(request.data())
    if data:
        if is_json(request.headers.get('Content-Type', '')):
            redir_input2 = json.dumps(data, indent=2, sort_keys=True,
                           separators=(',', ': '))
        else:
            redir_input2 = data
            
    # Output string
    output_string = f"{javascript_code}\n|\nconst aliasesData = {redir_input2};"

    return output_string
```

The python function returns a formatted string and then places it within [Sphinx CodeBlock](https://github.com/collective/sphinxcontrib-httpexample/blob/master/src/sphinxcontrib/httpexample/directives.py).

Modified Sphinx CodeBlock:

```
from docutils import nodes
from docutils.parsers.rst import directives
from docutils.statemachine import StringList
from sphinx.directives.code import CodeBlock
from sphinxcontrib.httpexample import builders
from sphinxcontrib.httpexample import parsers
from sphinxcontrib.httpexample import utils

import os
import re


AVAILABLE_BUILDERS = {
    'curl': (builders.build_curl_command, 'bash'),
    'wget': (builders.build_wget_command, 'bash'),
    'httpie': (builders.build_httpie_command, 'bash'),
    'requests': (builders.build_requests_command, 'python'),
    'python-requests': (builders.build_requests_command, 'python'),
    'plone_javascript': (builders.build_plone_javascript_command, 'javascript'),
}

AVAILABLE_FIELDS = [
    'query'
]


def choose_builders(arguments):
    return [directives.choice(argument, AVAILABLE_BUILDERS)
            for argument in (arguments or [])]


class HTTPExample(CodeBlock):

    required_arguments = 0
    optional_arguments = len(AVAILABLE_BUILDERS)

    option_spec = utils.merge_dicts(CodeBlock.option_spec, {
        'request': directives.unchanged,
        'response': directives.unchanged,
    })

    def run(self):
        config = self.state.document.settings.env.config

        # Read enabled builders; Defaults to None
        chosen_builders = choose_builders(self.arguments)

        # Enable 'http' language for http part
        self.arguments = ['http']

        # process 'query' reST fields
        if self.content:
            raw = ('\r\n'.join(self.content)).encode('utf-8')
            request = parsers.parse_request(raw)
            params, _ = request.extract_fields('query')
            params = [(p[1], p[2]) for p in params]
            new_path = utils.add_url_params(request.path, params)
            self.content[0] = ' '.join(
                [request.command, new_path, request.request_version])

        # split the request and optional response in the content.
        # The separator is two empty lines followed by a line starting with
        # 'HTTP/' or 'HTTP '
        request_content = StringList()
        request_content_no_fields = StringList()
        response_content = None
        emptylines_count = 0
        in_response = False
        is_field = r':({}) (.+): (.+)'.format('|'.join(AVAILABLE_FIELDS))
        for i, line in enumerate(self.content):
            source = self.content.source(i)
            if in_response:
                response_content.append(line, source)
            else:
                if emptylines_count >= 2 and \
                        (line.startswith('HTTP/') or line.startswith('HTTP ')):
                    in_response = True
                    response_content = StringList()
                    response_content.append(line, source)
                elif line == '':
                    emptylines_count += 1
                else:
                    request_content.extend(
                        StringList([''] * emptylines_count, source))
                    request_content.append(line, source)

                    if not re.match(is_field, line):
                        request_content_no_fields.extend(
                            StringList([''] * emptylines_count, source))
                        request_content_no_fields.append(line, source)

                    emptylines_count = 0

        # Load optional external request
        cwd = os.path.dirname(self.state.document.current_source)
        if 'request' in self.options:
            request = utils.resolve_path(self.options['request'], cwd)
            with open(request) as fp:
                request_content = request_content_no_fields = StringList(
                    list(map(str.rstrip, fp.readlines())), request)

        # Load optional external response
        if 'response' in self.options:
            response = utils.resolve_path(self.options['response'], cwd)
            with open(response) as fp:
                response_content = StringList(
                    list(map(str.rstrip, fp.readlines())), response)

        # reset the content to the request, stripped of the reST fields
        self.content = request_content_no_fields

        # Wrap and render main directive as 'http-example-http'
        klass = 'http-example-http'
        container = nodes.container('', classes=[klass])
        container.append(nodes.caption('', 'http'))
        container.extend(super(HTTPExample, self).run())

        # Init result node list
        result = [container]

        # reset the content to just the request
        self.content = request_content

        # Append builder responses
        if request_content_no_fields:
            raw = ('\r\n'.join(request_content_no_fields)).encode('utf-8')
            for name in chosen_builders:
                request = parsers.parse_request(raw, config.httpexample_scheme)
                builder_, language = AVAILABLE_BUILDERS[name]

                
                name = 'JavaScript' if name == 'plone_javascript' else name
                
                command = builder_(request)

                content = StringList(
                    [command], request_content_no_fields.source(0))
                options = self.options.copy()
                options.pop('name', None)
                options.pop('caption', None)

                block = CodeBlock(
                    'code-block',
                    [language],
                    options,
                    content,
                    self.lineno,
                    self.content_offset,
                    self.block_text,
                    self.state,
                    self.state_machine
                )

                # Wrap and render main directive as 'http-example-{name}'
                klass = 'http-example-{}'.format(name)
                container = nodes.container('', classes=[klass])
                container.append(nodes.caption('', name))
                container.extend(block.run())

                # Append to result nodes
                result.append(container)

        # Append optional response
        if response_content:
            options = self.options.copy()
            options.pop('name', None)
            options.pop('caption', None)

            block = CodeBlock(
                'code-block',
                ['http'],
                options,
                response_content,
                self.lineno,
                self.content_offset,
                self.block_text,
                self.state,
                self.state_machine
            )

            # Wrap and render main directive as 'http-example-response'
            klass = 'http-example-response'
            container = nodes.container('', classes=[klass])
            container.append(nodes.caption('', 'response'))
            container.extend(block.run())

            # Append to result nodes
            result.append(container)

        # Final wrap
        container_node = nodes.container('', classes=['http-example'])
        container_node.extend(result)

        return [container_node]
```

Output :

```
createAliasesMutation | const aliasesData = { "items": [ { "datetime": "2022-05-05", "path": "/old-page", "redirect-to": "/front-page" }, { "datetime": "2022-05-05", "path": "/fizzbuzz", "redirect-to": "/front-page" } ] };
```

Desired Output (something like this):

```
createAliasesMutation 
| 
const aliasesData =
{
    "items": [
        {
            "path": "/new-alias"
        },
        {
            "path": "/old-alias"
        },
        {
            "path": "/final-alias"
        }
    ]
}
```

Literal HTML:

```
<pre id="codecell19"><span></span><span class="nx">createAliasesMutation</span>
<span class="o">|</span>
<span class="kd">const</span><span class="w"> </span><span class="nx">aliasesData</span><span class="w"> </span><span class="o">=</span><span class="w"> </span><span class="p">{</span>
<span class="w">  </span><span class="s2">"items"</span><span class="o">:</span><span class="w"> </span><span class="p">[</span>
<span class="w">    </span><span class="p">{</span>
<span class="w">      </span><span class="s2">"datetime"</span><span class="o">:</span><span class="w"> </span><span class="s2">"2022-05-05"</span><span class="p">,</span>
<span class="w">      </span><span class="s2">"path"</span><span class="o">:</span><span class="w"> </span><span class="s2">"/old-page"</span><span class="p">,</span>
<span class="w">      </span><span class="s2">"redirect-to"</span><span class="o">:</span><span class="w"> </span><span class="s2">"/front-page"</span>
<span class="w">    </span><span class="p">},</span>
<span class="w">    </span><span class="p">{</span>
<span class="w">      </span><span class="s2">"datetime"</span><span class="o">:</span><span class="w"> </span><span class="s2">"2022-05-05"</span><span class="p">,</span>
<span class="w">      </span><span class="s2">"path"</span><span class="o">:</span><span class="w"> </span><span class="s2">"/fizzbuzz"</span><span class="p">,</span>
<span class="w">      </span><span class="s2">"redirect-to"</span><span class="o">:</span><span class="w"> </span><span class="s2">"/front-page"</span>
<span class="w">    </span><span class="p">}</span>
<span class="w">  </span><span class="p">]</span>
<span class="p">};</span>
</pre>
```

I tried using `.replace('\\n','\n')` from this [stackoverflow issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39414569/how-to-print-the-line-breaks-of-a-json-attribute-using-python) but still didnt work.

Edit: I am posting this issue again since I didnt added all the details in my earlier post.

Comment: Where are you getting the output? In your browser?

Comment: Yes, on my localhost after running the project locally. You can check out the GitHub repo from the given Sphinx link

Comment: In that case, the literal HTML would be more useful. If you right click and select "View source" or equivalent and copy-paste the relevant HTML into your question, I think I can probably figure out the answer for you.

Comment: I've added the literal HTML of the request body output in the post.

Comment: Can you include the 3 surrounding `<div>`s in your HTML sample by editing your question? When I inspect the http request example at https://6.docs.plone.org/plone.restapi/docs/source/endpoints/aliases.html#adding-new-url-aliases-for-a-page I see more HTML with more styles getting applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely [here](https://github.com/collective/sphinxcontrib-httpexample/blob/master/src/sphinxcontrib/httpexample/static/sphinxcontrib-httpexample.css#L18):

```
.http-example div[class^='highlight'] pre {
    white-space: normal;
}
```

I'm not sure *why* they added this, but the [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) property being set to `normal` collapses all white space (including newlines) into a single space. It is the default for most elements, but for `pre`, the default is `pre`, which is likely what's needed for your use case.

Comment: Line 17 gets overridden by line 24 in the same file.